# How to host an ASP.Net application in a server where SharePoint 2013 is installed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I have SharePoint 2013 with application url for example: https://intra.abc.org

now I have another (CarTracking) ASP.Net MVC application  want to host it in this server

for example: https://intra.abc.org/CarTracking

but it give bellow error:

> Server Error in '/CarTracking' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

than I turned off the custom error and I get the following error

> ```
> Server Error in '/CarTracking' Application.
>
> Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.
> ```
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.
>
> Source Error: 
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> ```
>
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> ```
> Stack Trace: 
>
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.]
> ```
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore(CallSite`1
>   site, Object[] args) +5937252
>
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2(CallSite site, T0
>   arg0, T1 arg1) +928
>         VRM5.Controllers.VRsController.Create() in   C:\Users\mehdi.jalal\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\VRM5\VRM5\Controllers\VRsController.cs:233
>
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +242
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +139
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +112    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +452    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +37    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +241
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +19
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +542    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +299

Answer (score -1):

There's two things to suggest here:

1. In IIS, at the folder level for "CarTracking", you need to create a new Application (in IIS-sense), so your app is hosted in a dedicated app domain (in the sense of .NET). You may also choose to host this new application in a dedicated app pool but that's not mandatory.
2. You need to edit your `web.config` file in "CarTracking" to add back all HTTP modules removed explicitly by SharePoint in its own `web.config`: `AnonymousIdentification`, `FileAuthorization`, `Profile`, `WebDAVModule` and `Session`. Also remove explicitely added modules. So, you'd end-up with somthing like this in your own web.config for your app:

   ```
   <add name="AnonymousIdentification" type="System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule" />
   <add name="FileAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule" />
   <add name="Profile" type="System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule" />
   <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>

   <remove name="SPNativeRequestModule" />
   <remove name="SPRequestModule" />
   <remove name="ScriptModule" />
   <remove name="SharePoint14Module" />
   <remove name="StateServiceModule" />
   <remove name="PublishingHttpModule" />
   <remove name="DesignHttpModule" />
   <remove name="FederatedAuthentication" />
   <remove name="SessionAuthentication" />
   <remove name="SPWindowsClaimsAuthentication" />
   <remove name="SPApplicationAuthentication" />
   <remove name="Session" />
   ```

Comment: can you provide details, in your answer from where should I start and what should I change